# Was Nora's departed Husband also Tom's Biological Father?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-leftovers

I was scratching my head about this one but I am trying to find out if I interpreted this scene correctly from Season 3 Episode 2 ["Don't Be Ridiculous"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5337978/).  Nora and Tom are talking in the car about him being adopted.

Tom mentions when he was told he was adopted that he looked for 10 years for his biological father, and when he found him, he mentioned he had a family and kids and wanted nothing to do with them.

Later Nora laments that she wishes Tom had never left the baby on her doorstep that day, and Tom replies,

> I didn't leave her for you... I left her for my dad

That got me thinking, he thought Nora's house was his biological Dads house, and he probably didnt even know who Nora was. That would mean Noras departed husband is in fact Tom's biological dad and neither of the characters probably know this yet.

Somebody I was talking to insists that Tom didnt leave the baby at Noras house and instead left it at his adopted Dads house, which is a far less interesting outcome because that just means he couldnt take care of the baby and was dumping it on his adopted Dad Kevin to take care of.

So I am confused now, which of us are right here? Do we actually know who Toms biological dad is at this point in the series?

Comment: Definitely the baby was left at Kevin's doorsteps. Nora went there to leave a letter telling him she was planning to leave town, and she found the baby there first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't remember which house he left the baby at - I think the intention was to leave it with Nora and Kevin. However, Tom's biological Dad (Michael) appeared in [S1 Ep9](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3721722/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) and is played by Scott William Winters, so he definitely isn't Nora's husband (who already departed at that point).

ISTR the plot of that episode resulting in someone punching someone else - possibly Kevin punching Michael. Could be wrong though.

I think in the quote you've, er, quoted, he is referring to Kevin as his Dad which would explain your confusion.

Answer (score 6):

In the full context of the conversation, Tom talks about Kevin adopting him at an early age, and him not knowing any differently.  He talks about his biological father using exactly that term - biological father.

So, when he says he left it for his "dad," he means Kevin.  When he says that he left it for Kevin, not her, he specifically states that he didn't even know that she and Kevin were together, and that he didn't even know who she was at that time.